# How do I reset the Entry widget background color back to the default system color in GtkSharp?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk3

I'm using GtkSharp and trying to recreate the 7GUIS [flight booker](https://eugenkiss.github.io/7guis/tasks#flight) app. I'm running into trouble resetting the background color to the system's default theme for an Entry. When I hit the "Book" button I set the both entries backgrounds to red if one of the fields is empty and the return flights option is checked

```
        bookButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (bookMenu.ActiveText == "return flight")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entryDeparture.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entryReturn.Text))
                {
                    entryDeparture.ModifyBg(StateType.Normal, new Gdk.Color(255, 0, 0));
                    entryReturn.ModifyBg(StateType.Normal, new Gdk.Color(255, 0, 0));
                }
            }
        };
```

But if the person then switches to one-way flight in the drop down menu both entries' background will still be red. I want to set them back to the dark grey color the system displays at the default when the ComboTextBox is changed, but I've only successfully reset it to black.I know I shouldn't be using Gdk.Color here, but trying to access the background through the original style doesn't seem to be working.

```
        bookMenu.Changed += (sender, e) => {
            entryReturn.Sensitive = bookMenu.ActiveText == "return flight";
            entryDeparture.ModifyBg(StateType.Normal, new Gdk.Color(0,0,0));
            entryReturn.ModifyBg(StateType.Normal, new Gdk.Color(0,0,0));
        };
```

The full code [can be found here](https://pastebin.com/q1USN8fY)

Comment: `ModifyBg` is deprecated.  You want to be using `gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen` to set the CSS, `gtk_style_context_add_class`,  and `gtk_style_context_remove_class`. There are also various defined colors such as `@theme_base_color` that can be used.